# Failing to convert string to dict in python due to quotes

Tags: python

I have a huge response which contains strings similar to `a = '{"key1": "The sample "data", to convert to dict"}'`.
I want to convert this to dict.
I am using json.loads() but it's failing due to quotes.
I have tried eval() but I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: Change `"data"` to `\"data\"`.

Comment: In this case, I can change easily, but in the response string which I have. It's quite impossible.

Comment: If the response sends content like ``'{"key1": "The sample "data", to convert to dict"}'``, then it does not send JSON – do not attempt to load it as such! Figure out what the format is and use that.

Comment: So you have data in an *invalid format*. That's… tough. If syntax is broken, it's very difficult to fix that programmatically, since if the program could unambiguously understand the data and fix it, it could understand the original data and wouldn't need to raise a syntax error in the first place…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution for this on my own.

In cases like this `a = '{"key1": "The sample "data", to convert to dict"}'` where facing issue with quotes to convert string to JSON.

`a = '{"key1": "The sample \\"data\\", to convert to dict"}'`. This will work.

And if the string is very large and it's not possible to change at each and every place you can follow the below solution.

1. a look like this inititally {"key1": "The sample "data", to convert to dict"}'
2. First replace all the " with \". `a = a.replace('"', '\\"')`
3. Now a looks like this {\"key1\": \"The sample \"data\", to convert to dict\"}.
4. Then replace { and } with "{ and }" correspondingly. `a  = a.replace('{', '"{').replace('}', '}"')`.
5. Now a looks like this "{\"key1\": \"The sample \"data\", to convert to dict\"}".
6. json.loads(a). This will work for sure.

Comment: "json.loads(a). This will work for sure." Because it parses what is now a JSON *string literal* – it simply recovers the initial string ``'{"key1": "The sample "data", to convert to dict"}'``.

Comment: MisterMiyagi, `'{"key1": "The sample "data", to convert to dict"}'` json.loads() doesn't work on this string. I have tried it. If you think it will work can you please send a snap of the successful json loading.

Comment: I'm not saying it works. I'm saying your recipe from 1. to 6. just recovers the original string. Most importantly, it does not load the dictionary as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think like a computer! How would you divide this string:

`"The sample "data", to convert to dict"`

Like this: "The sample " -> random `data` variable that probably doesn't exist -> ", to convert to dict".

The solution? Either escape the inner `"` or alternate between `"` and `'`. But the latter doesn't look possible here so you want:

`'{"key1": "The sample \"data\", to convert to dict"}'`

edit: Apparently there's some details missing in your question, could you update it?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the response.
But this '{"key1": "The sample \"data\", to convert to dict"}' won't work. This will work {"key1": "The sample \\"data\\", to convert to dict"}'

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your dealing with invalid input data. If your forced to use it, and the only incompatibility is the existence of quotes in the middle of the data, then we can use a few properties of json to our advantage.

Taking your string *a* as presented:

*b* will be the returned string cleaning of miscreant " entries.

```
b = a[0:2]  #Opening
for i1 in range(2, len(a)-2):
    if a[i1] == '"' and \
        (a[i1-1] not in ["{","}",":"] and \
         a[i1+1] not in ["{","}",":"] and \
        a[i1-2:i1] not in ["{ ", ": "] and \
        a[i1+1:i1+2] not in [" }", " :"]):
            
        #This is one we'd not want to include
        dummy = 1        
        
    else:
        b = b + a[i1]
b = b + a[len(a)-2:len(a)]  #And closing
```

So basically, if the quotes are not near "{", "}" or ":", then it doesn't concatenate them into the return string. Very ugly and very problem specific - but it might get you out of a hole.

Then obviously, json.loads(b) should give you want you want.

I know my inverse logic above is a little unconventional, but I find it easier to think that way rather than try and get tangled up in nots (see what I did there? :-D)

Comment: Can you please explain how the code works? What's the point of ``dummy = 1``? Seeing how the initial problem is a maintenance issue, adding another on top to fix it seems counter productive. A ``filter`` or comprehension+``''.join`` might be more readable. By the way, "use a few properties of json to our advantage" seems like a dangerous thing to do when the input is not JSON.

Comment: Of course its dangerous - but if they are faced with no alternative (as highlighted at the start of my response) then its a starting point. If we want a JSON out, then we are using a few properties of JSON to produce a JSON compatible string. If you want to use join, or code a filter, go ahead. This works and is understandable for me. The use of dummy = 1 is explained within the initial response.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are not actually using ``dummy`` – [``pass`` would be appropriate if it is indeed a "do nothing"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement).

Comment: It would be alright. But I never thought of putting it in during the few seconds I was scribbling a solution out in work.